# EventReservation won't reschedule/cancel

Tags: gmail, google-schemas

I can schedule events using gMail markup, but...

- If I attempt to reschedule an event, it just makes a second copy at the new time, and leaves the original event intact.
- If I attempt to cancel an event, nothing happens.

An example of what my confirmation looks like:

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/EventReservation">
  <meta itemprop="reservationId" content="Example967585">
  <link itemprop="reservationStatus" href="http://schema.org/ReservationConfirmed">
  <div itemprop="underName" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Sam Brown">
  </div>
  <div itemprop="reservationFor" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">

    <meta itemprop="name" content="The Return of the Sam Exclusive Experience">
    <meta itemprop="eventStatus" content="http://schema.org/EventScheduled">
    <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2019-12-20T10:00:00-08:00">
    <meta itemprop="endDate" content="2019-12-20T11:00:00-08:00">
    <div itemprop="location" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
      <meta itemprop="name" content="851 81st Avenue">
      <div itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="851 81st Avenue">
        <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="San Francisco">
        <meta itemprop="addressRegion" content="CA">
        <meta itemprop="postalCode" content="94105">
        <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="SE">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a sample reschedule markup:

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/EventReservation">
  <meta itemprop="reservationId" content="Example967585">
  <link itemprop="reservationStatus" href="http://schema.org/ReservationConfirmed">
  <div itemprop="underName" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Sam Brown">
  </div>
  <div itemprop="reservationFor" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">

    <meta itemprop="name" content="The Return of the Sam Exclusive Experience">
    <meta itemprop="eventStatus" content="http://schema.org/EventRescheduled">
    <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2019-12-21T10:00:00-08:00">
    <meta itemprop="endDate" content="2019-12-21T11:00:00-08:00">
    <div itemprop="location" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
      <meta itemprop="name" content="851 81st Avenue">
      <div itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="851 81st Avenue">
        <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="San Francisco">
        <meta itemprop="addressRegion" content="CA">
        <meta itemprop="postalCode" content="94105">
        <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="SE">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <meta itemprop="modifiedTime" content="2019-12-19T15:15:40-08:00">
</div>
```

Finally, a sample cancellation markup:

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/EventReservation">
  <meta itemprop="reservationId" content="Example967585">
  <link itemprop="reservationStatus" href="http://schema.org/ReservationCancelled">
  <div itemprop="underName" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Sam Brown">
  </div>
  <div itemprop="reservationFor" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">

    <meta itemprop="name" content="The Return of the Sam Exclusive Experience">
    <meta itemprop="eventStatus" content="http://schema.org/EventCancelled">
    <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2019-12-21T10:00:00-08:00">
    <meta itemprop="endDate" content="2019-12-21T11:00:00-08:00">
    <div itemprop="location" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
      <meta itemprop="name" content="851 81st Avenue">
      <div itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="851 81st Avenue">
        <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="San Francisco">
        <meta itemprop="addressRegion" content="CA">
        <meta itemprop="postalCode" content="94105">
        <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="SE">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <meta itemprop="modifiedTime" content="2019-12-19T15:26:23-08:00">
</div>
```

Other than being run through a translator to take them out of Quoted Printable format, those are live examples, cut&pasted directly from the eMails they were sent through.

All three markups pass the testing tool at:
https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#

A subset of the things I've tried:

- Using the sample code from the markup page.
- Updating that code to the newest versions I can find at schema.org.
  ** e.g. Changing reservationNumber to reservationId.
  ** e.g. Changing the reservation status to match the ReservationStatus types shown on schema.org rather than the versions from the markup tutorial page.
- Testing by eMailing the markup to myself, using the markup email testing script at https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial and the sample code from the markup eventReservation page.
- Swapping from the microdata example to the json+ld example when using that self test script.

I'm stumped for more things to try.

Comment: The documentation mentions a `reservationNumber` instead of a `reservationId`, which one is accepted by Google now? https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has confirmed via eMail that cancelling events and removing duplicate events after a reschedule was removed as a feature in December.

I've asked them to update their documentation.

Comment: Damn that's a shame. But thanks for updating that question, was trying to figure the same thing and was at a loss.