# Can't cancel an EventReservation

Tags: gmail, markup, google-schemas

I'm allowed to send Gmail Schemas of `"EventReservation"` type (with `"reservationStatus" = "http://schema.org/Confirmed"`), and they're inserting themselves automatically to Google Calendar as expected, but there's no way I can cancel one of those events.

I've tried changing the `"reservationStatus"` parameter to `"https://schema.org/Cancelled"` and  `"https://schema.org/ReservationCancelled"` (as mentioned in schema.org) but it didn't work.

I [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59418177/eventreservation-wont-reschedule-cancel) that Google removed that feature on Dec. '19, but again there was a [publication on Google Developer](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/03/new-properties-virtual-or-canceled-events) on Mar '20 that says that they enabled event cancellation in schemas (not specifically in Gmail), but those tips didn't work either.

Both JSON+LD structures are the same except for the keys mentioned above.